# dnsmasq parallel queries waiting for positive response

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, coredns

my dnsmasq.conf currently have a few upstream servers

```
all-servers
dns-loop-detect
no-resolv

server=10.0.0.100
server=10.0.0.101    
server=192.168.53.1
server=192.168.53.2
```

and depending on which server responds first, sometimes the client gets a `NXDOMAIN` reponse.

but i would like to try another server prior to sending a negative response.

is there a way to make `dnsmasq` behave like the [fanout plugin for CoreDNS](https://coredns.io/explugins/fanout/) ?

> Each incoming DNS query that hits the CoreDNS fanout plugin will be replicated in parallel to each listed IP (i.e. the DNS servers).
> The first non-negative response from any of the queried DNS Servers will be forwarded as a response to the application’s DNS request.

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, but I don't think dnsmasq can do what you want. Have a look maybe at `dnsdist` that is more versatil around nameservers selection. It is more suited for authoritative nameservers, but maybe it could work in your setup. You may however also take a step back and rethink the whole strategy as having multiple servers responding completely differently to the same query may be a bigger problem, as it looks like some kind of split view, which has to be treated carefully, to avoid side effects. And if DNSSEC is in the party, expect headache

Answer (score 0):

you can filter NXDOMAIN replies from upstream DNS servers using iptables.

This way dnsmasq will timeout rather then get NXDOMAIN

When pairred with all-servers dnsmasq config option this shoud achive what You want.
Example rules:

```
#iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.0.100/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -m u32 --u32 "0x36&0xf=0x3" -j DROP
#iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.0.100/32 -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -m u32 --u32 "0x1c&0xf=0x3" -j DROP
```

You should put those 2 rules for each of upstream DNS servers